# How to retain the form of the function on different domain in mathematica

Tags: plotting, functions

I have two functions f1 and f2, now I wanted to retains the forms of the these two functions on different domain. like if I change the domain from `{x,0,Pi}` to `{x,0,2Pi}`. what changes I have to make to functions to achive this. I looking at the functions, I know it is kind of dumb, but is there way to stretch the function.

```
f1 = Sin[x]
f2 = 2*Sin[x]

Plot[{f1, f2}, {x, 0, \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is an example of a function transformation. Stretching in $x$ direction is achieved by multiplying the argument ($x$) with a factor. Example: ``f[x_] := Sin[x]; Plot[{f[x], f[2 x], f[x/2]}, {x, 0, \[Pi]}]``. Multiplying with 2 stretches it, dividing by 2 squeezes it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Reply to comment**

When the scaling factors are `{sx,sy}`,we translate the point `{x1,y1}` to `{sx*x1,sy*y1}={x,y}`,so `{x1,y1}={x/sx,y/sy}`, it means that `y/sy=f[x/sx]`,that is `y=sy*f[x/sx]`.

```
Clear[f1, f2, sx, sy];
f1[x_] = Sin[x];
f2[x_] = 2*Sin[x];
{sx, sy} = {4, 2};
Show[Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, π}], 
 Plot[{sy*f1[(x - 0)/sx], sy*f2[(x - 0)/sx]}, {x, sx*0, sx*π}], 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

**Original**

Use `ScalingTransform`.

```
Clear[f1, f2, plot];
f1 = Sin[x];
f2 = 2*Sin[x];
plot = Plot[{f1, f2}, {x, 0, π}];
Show[plot, 
 Graphics[
  GeometricTransformation[plot[[1]], ScalingTransform[{4, 2},{0,0}]]], 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: What changes I need to fo to the function to achive this, Instead of using the inbuilt transformation function. beacuse I need to perfom mathematical operation on the resultant transformation.

Comment: Could you explain it briefly, what is cx and cy, by looking at it I can see it is a scaling variables. But could you explain it little